# Middleware with one ServerSocket or two ServerSockets

Tags: java, websocket

I have implemeted app and server side. The App has a Socket and the server side has a ServerSocket as well as socket to talk with the Android app.
Now I want to extend my application to work as in the image below. 
My questtion do I need in the connector1 and connector2 (Where the green question marks are) a second ServerSocket and socket?

What I think: in the connector1 and connector2 I need ServerSocket like:

```
ServerSocket connector1ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(7510);
Socket connector1clientSocket = connector1ServerSocket .accept();
```

The `outputStream` of `connector1clientSocket` to send a reponse to the app. Therefore, I need in the connector1 a second socket and in the conenctor2 second ServerSocket+Socket.

Notice: The app and the Client in the new modul must have just a Socket.

[image]

Comment: If you want to accept connection, then obviously you need `ServerSocket`. However, your question is quite unclear.